# Why is Player's generic.movementSpeed Attribute listed on Wiki as lower than ALL Mobs, yet you can clearly outrun all of them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

EDIT: Player's generic.movementSpeed SPRINTING Attribute is listed as 0.15, their WALK speed is listed as even slower (0.1)

Original Post:

A Player's generic.movementSpeed Attribute is listed as 0.15 but a Zombie's is 0.23. We all know players can outrun zombies. I know the English Wiki says that the final number is "about 43 times higher" than generic.movementSpeed value and describes the final value as "Speed of movement in some unknown metric".

I found a foreign language wiki states the equation for speed is: y = 43.178x-0.02141 but as far as I know math that still won't make 0.15 "faster" than 0.23... This foreign wiki even goes as far as to use the formula to calculate a Players final running speed as 6.5m/s when a Zombie has 9.9m/s. There is no similar calculation on the English wiki, but the same calculations are mirrored in an English Wiki "Talk Page" from 2013.

It also seems like all the mobs have appropriate values as the faster mobs have higher numbers; spiders being a 0.3 compared to a Zombie's 0.23 makes sense to what I've seen reflected in-game, just the Player's speed sticks stand out as an oddity.

Then, to top it all off, both Wikis list a "Default Base" of 0.7 for ALL players and mobs... but doesn't say when or how it's applied when all players and mobs all have their own speeds set already.

Any insight? Or is this still an "unknown metric" 7 years on?

Comment: Since we all probably instinctly sprint whenever we walk you might not realize it, but if you ever just walk without sprinting it's super slow

Comment: I believe that doesn't take sprinting into account. You can out-run all enemies, but not necessarily out-walk them, so to speak.

Comment: @Sam Hill yes that's what I meant. Although I'm not sure what the sprint speed is, I 100% agree with you that he has got to be talking about wall speed, a sprinting player is faster than nearly all entities

Comment: The table you appear to be looking at includes baby zombies and normal zombies as one. Note all mobs with generic.movement_speed of 0.23 (other than aggravated sheep and blazes) all are mobs with "baby" variants that can run faster than normal.

Comment: I think the only suggestion that is worth contemplating is that the chart is not accurate. I don't know of any other place that base speeds would be listed or explained. Has anyone that has modified  entity speeds with commands or datapacks have any insight on what the numbers actually are? I also just did a /data get on a villager and it says that his current Base is 1.0 .... on the wiki it is listed as 0.5...